# I'm trying to run hbase shell and i get a wrongNumberOfArguments error

Tags: hbase

I know that the question has been asked before, but the answers don't seem to be working for me. I am trying to run hbase shell in windows 10 while i get the following error:

```
c:\hbase-1.4.12\bin>hbase shell
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jruby.java.invokers.RubyToJavaInvoker (file:/C:/hbase-1.4.12/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar) to method java.lang.Object.registerNatives()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jruby.java.invokers.RubyToJavaInvoker
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
  method_added at file:/C:/hbase-1.4.12/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/builtin/javasupport/core_ext/object.rb:10
  method_added at file:/C:/hbase-1.4.12/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/builtin/javasupport/core_ext/object.rb:129
       Pattern at file:/C:/hbase-1.4.12/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/builtin/java/java.util.regex.rb:2
        (root) at file:/C:/hbase-1.4.12/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/builtin/java/java.util.regex.rb:1
       require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1062
        (root) at file:/C:/hbase-1.4.12/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/builtin/java/java.util.regex.rb:42
        (root) at c:\hbase-1.4.12\bin\..\bin\hirb.rb:38
```

java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)
```

my hbase-env.sh contains the following line:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jre1.8.0_241
```

I don't know if there is a problem with space character in "program files" or something else. Hbase-start runs fine and i have the master running perfectly in local mode. I'd appreciate your help.